# Rails 3 uninitialized constant when using thread

Tags: multithreading, ruby-on-rails-3, rake-task

i am running rails 3 thread to improve the performance of the rake task. sometimes i am getting uninitialized constant when i am trying to access outside class from my current class.  as an example when i am trying to access `NotificationService` class from `NotificationApp` as shown below then getting error as uninitialized constant `NotificationService`. This error is not coming every time. sometimes rake task is running fine without the error and sometimes same rake is failing with uninitialized constant. what could be the reason for this and how can i fix this issue?

```
class NotificationApp < ActiveRecord::Base
  def signal_event
    NotificationService.notify
  end
end
```

Edit

This is how i am creating threadpool

```
class ThreadPool
  def initialize(size)
    @size = size
    @jobs = Queue.new
    @pool = Array.new(@size) do |i|
      Thread.new do
        Thread.current[:id] = i
        catch(:exit) do
          loop do
            job, args = @jobs.pop
            job.call(*args)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # add a job to queue
  def schedule(*args, &block)
    @jobs << [block, args]
  end

  # run threads and perform jobs from queue
  def run!
    @size.times do
      schedule { throw :exit }
    end
    @pool.map(&:join)
  end

  # get all threads created 
  def threads
    @pool
  end

  def complete!
    @pool.each{|t| t.kill}
  end
end
```

and this is how i am using threads

```
def perform
    ReadReplicaHelper.read_from_slave do
      pool = ThreadPool.new(CONNECTION_POOL_COUNT - 1)
      device_ids.in_groups_of(1000, false) do |devices|
        devices.each do |device_id|
          device = Device.find_by_id(device_id)
          if device
            ReadReplicaHelper.read_from_master do
              Notification.where(device_id: device_id).each do |notification|
                pool.schedule do
                  pool_method notification, last_status, before_last_status
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
      # Run the Thread Pool
      pool.run!

      # Kill the threads created in the pool
      pool.complete!

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `NotificationService` class is in a file named `app/services/notification_service.rb` and that you are loading this services directory.

Also as you are using threads, make sure to `join` all the threads after calling them

Comment: Hi Dorian,

NotificationService is in class app/services/notification_service.rb and service directory is in config.autoload_paths .. do i have to explicitly require file..

Comment: no you shouldn't explicitly require file, but are you joining your threads, e.g. `threads.each(&:join)`

Comment: yes..i am doing it.. the error i am getting is not coming every-time but sometime..

Comment: can you share the code of when you execute those threads?

Comment: I have updated my code.